# How to place lateral buttons to an iframe (for all browsers)?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to dynamically create iframes and to put some buttons (in column) on right of them, with buttons positions that follow the iframes ones.

I tried all the settings of

```
button.style.position = " "
```

inserting "absolute", "relative", etc. and trying to specify the pixel positions, but it doesn't work.

However, I have noticed that opening the same page with different browsers the buttons are placed in different positions.

I need a method that allows me to place the buttons at the right of the iframe, following its position and above all that returns the same result with all most used browsers.

What technique can I use?

Comment: Can you provide some code for the iframe generating part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats wrong with the basic premise of

```
    <div id="left">
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <button>first button</button>
    <button>second button</button>
</div> 

#left, #right {
    float:left;
    width:46%;
    height:300px;
    margin:2%;
}
iframe {
    width:100%;
}
button {
    width:100%;
    clear:right;
}
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/PsHGp/)